# What sand is best for thin-set mortar?

Tags: grout, mortar

I understand that unmodified thin-set mortar is typically 25-35% portland with most of the balance being a fine sand.  If I wanted to make my own where could I obtain this fine sand?  What is it called and how is it graded?

Comment: Why would you want to make your own?

Comment: Agree with bib. I've made plenty of my own batches of concrete and brick mortar but I don't mess around when it comes to thin-set.